# Orfox does not load sites

Tags: nyx

Not even https://check.torproject.org/ (get white page) works fine on Firefox beta when it is selected in orbot. But there you get this warning: However, it does not appear to be Tor Browser. Click here to go to the download page.

Tryed with vpn/bridges. Same problem. Worked yesterday. Had to open port (9050/9040/5400) all udp and port trigger on Asus rt-ac68u stock firmware.

Newest ver of orbot and orfox. Android 5 sm-g870f unrooted.